# map Function Not Found When Reading from JSON File

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-scripts

I created a React app with this command: npx create-react-app test-project

I have a small JSON file:

```
{
    "colors": [
        {
            "id": 0, 
            "name": "red"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "green"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "blue"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3, 
            "name": "yellow"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am trying to display it in a list in React.

```
import {colors} from "./colors.json";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {colors.map((c, i) => 
          <li>{c.name}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 11:16-26

export 'colors'.'map' (imported as 'colors') was not found in './colors.json' (possible exports: 0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Because this project is pulled from a larger project, I happen to know what the issue is. In the package.json file, my react-scripts version is 5.0.0. If I downgrade it to 4.0.1, the issue resolves.

However, as someone who is learning React, I would like to understand why this error occurs. I don't understand why it is no longer able to recognize that an array from a JSON file would have a map function defined. I would definitely prefer the behavior found when I set react-scripts to 4.0.1.

Is this a bug or a feature? I have examined the [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) for react-scripts 5.0.0, but don't see anything relevant.

Comment: For react script 5.0.0 is also working. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-benz-e79wvq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @decpk Hm, not in Visual Studio Code. I build with "npm install" and then run with "npm start", and I always get that error. The only difference is when I flip the version of react-scripts. (Thanks for checking.)